# Can I avoid a sorted dictionary output after I've used pprint.pprint, in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, pretty-print, pprint

The code is:

```
from pprint import pprint
d = {"b" : "Maria", "c" : "Helen", "a" : "George"}
pprint(d, width = 1)
```

The output is:

```
{'a': 'George',
'b': 'Maria',
'c': 'Helen'}
```

But, the desired output is:

```
{'b': 'Maria',
'c': 'Helen',
'a': 'George'}
```

Could this be done with pprint or is there another way?

Comment: `OrderedDict` or use a function to sort over keys and print them individually. But as another note, why do you care if a dictionary has an order?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html says, "Dictionaries are sorted by key before the display is computed." Doesn't make it sound like it's optional.

Comment: @EdChum, @Francisco, sure, OrderedDict will display the results in ordered order. But if you pass one to pprint, it won't be "pretty": it will look like `OrderedDict([items go here])`. Doesn't look much like the desired output.

Comment: @Kevin I just noticed that bit, you're correct this is unavoidable with `pprint` so the OP needs to consider a different metho

Comment: You might be able to subclass `PrettyPrinter` and override `pformat` to get your desired output.  I'm not sure though

Comment: @Kevin, Sure, but if I use a simple print, then I take an unsorted result, as I want. The problem with that is that I have to print the dict exactly as the output shows above, but simple print prints everything in one line, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Python 3.8 or newer:

You can use `sort_dicts=False` to prevent it from sorting them alphabetically:

```
pprint.pprint(data, sort_dicts=False)
```

#### Python 3.7 or older:

Since Python 3.7 (or 3.6 in the case of cPython), `dict` preserves insertion order. For any version prior, you will need to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep keys in order.

Although, from the [doc on `pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html):

> Dictionaries are sorted by key before the display is computed.

This means `pprint` will break your desired order regardless.

#### Alternative method:

You can also use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to pretty print your data.

**Code:**

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

# For Python 3.6 and prior, use an OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict(b="Maria", c="Helen", a="George")

print(json.dumps(d, indent=1))
```

**Output:**

```
{
 "b": "Maria",
 "c": "Helen",
 "a": "George"
}
```

Comment: Python 3.7 didn't work for that, but the last code is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.

Comment: @MariaPantsiou You are correct, pprint sorts your keys, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you read the source of `pprint.py` you'll find that in `PrettyPrinter._pprint_dict()`, the method responsible for formatting dicts:

```
def _pprint_dict(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level):
    write = stream.write
    write('{')
    if self._indent_per_level > 1:
        write((self._indent_per_level - 1) * ' ')
    length = len(object)
    if length:
        items = sorted(object.items(), key=_safe_tuple)
        self._format_dict_items(items, stream, indent, allowance + 1,
                                context, level)
    write('}')

_dispatch[dict.__repr__] = _pprint_dict
```

There's this line `items = sorted(object.items(), key=_safe_tuple)`, so dict items are always sorted first before being processed for formatting, and you will have to override it yourself by copying and pasting it and removing the offending line in your own script:

```
import pprint as pp
def _pprint_dict(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level):
    write = stream.write
    write('{')
    if self._indent_per_level > 1:
        write((self._indent_per_level - 1) * ' ')
    length = len(object)
    if length:
        self._format_dict_items(object.items(), stream, indent, allowance + 1,
                                context, level)
    write('}')
pp.PrettyPrinter._dispatch[dict.__repr__] = _pprint_dict
```

so that:

```
pp.pprint({"b" : "Maria", "c" : "Helen", "a" : "George"}, width=1)
```

will output (in Python 3.6+):

```
{'b': 'Maria',
 'c': 'Helen',
 'a': 'George'}
```

Comment: The issue I encountered when subclassing is that the private methods are called only when the standard representation exceeds the width. While you overcame the this problem by setting width=1, a general solution would require also overriding the PrettyPrinter.format method.

Comment: Indeed. I've added a new answer with a more generic approach.

Answer (score 4):

As of Python 3.8, pprint has a `sort_dicts` keyword argument you can set to prevent it from sorting dictionary keys alphabetically. If you set it to false, it will use the default ordering of dictionaries (e.g. insertion order).

Example:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dict(z=0, a=1), sort_dicts=False)
{'z': 0, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you, first answer that actually works and is simple

Answer (score 3):

A more generic solution is to use `unittest.mock.patch` to override the built-in `sorted` function with a function that does nothing but return the given first argument:

```
import pprint
from unittest.mock import patch

def unsorted_pprint(*args, **kwargs):
    with patch('builtins.sorted', new=lambda l, **_: l):
        orig_pprint(*args, **kwargs)

orig_pprint = pprint.pprint
pprint.pprint = unsorted_pprint
```

so that:

```
pprint.pprint({"b" : "Maria", "c" : "Helen", "a" : "George"})
```

outputs:

```
{'b': 'Maria', 'c': 'Helen', 'a': 'George'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use OrderedDict from the collections library of python to keep the ordering constant

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint
d = OrderedDict({"b" : "Maria", "c" : "Helen", "a" : "George"})
pprint(d, width = 1)
```

**UPDATE:**

Since output is important, you can use the following code, its a hack but you create a function to implement this feature:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict({"b" : "Maria", "c" : "Helen", "a" : "George"})
print('{', end='')
total_len = len(d)
current_index = 1
for key, value in d.items():
    print('\''+key+'\': \'' + value+ '\'', end='')
    if current_index<total_len:
        print(',')
    else:
        print('}')
    current_index += 1
```

Comment: The OP wants to modify the behaviour of `pprint`, this isn't about maintaining insertion order

Comment: pprint would be printing the output as per the value saved. dict by default doesn't maintain the order or insertion hence the output is printed in that order. Hence I feel using an ordereddict would serve the purpose

Comment: The output of this code doesn't look much like the desired output.

Comment: It does solve the sorting problem, but the output is quite different comparing to the desired one.

Comment: I have updated the answer to print it as per the requirement. I hope this solves your problem

Comment: @ Arghya Saha, Great, that solves my problem! Thank you!